# Excel - Vlookup within Vlookup dependent on drop-down

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, vlookup

Please bear with my explanation here - I want to be as clear as possible.  I have about **8 different tables** (different categories), which contain ranges that correspond to point values.  I have been using **VLOOKUP** for **each** category to calculate the number of points based on which range your input falls into.
[These are 2 examples of the charts w/lookup.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1FB9.png)

In another tab, I have an **input** column, a "**points**" column, and a **drop down list** of all 8 categories.  Again, each category corresponds to a **different** VLOOKUP.  I am trying to input an amount, and based on which category I select from the drop down, have Excel output the number of points I would earn (I have been trying to do this using VLOOKUP). It works for the first row, since in my final VLOOKUP it checks the first input value - but when I drag down the formula for many rows, it does not update to correspond to the input in that row (it only looks at that first input cell).  How can I make it so that the initial vlookup **takes the input of whatever row I'm currently in**?

[(see highlighted for relevant columns)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGrZH.png)

This is quite difficult to explain - let me know if any clarification is necessary.

Comment: In the interest of clarify, by [chart](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/available-chart-types-in-office-a6187218-807e-4103-9e0a-27cdb19afb90) to you mean [table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overview-of-Excel-tables-7AB0BB7D-3A9E-4B56-A3C9-6C94334E492C)? It would also be helpful to have sample data and the formulas you are using

Comment: yes table - will edit

Comment: @EmilyAnnDeChaira, Could you please share the VLOOKUP formula you have use I think in Col X,,, and getting error will help us to understand the source you have tried with it!! And the Formula in Col P also (2nd Screen Shot)

Answer (score 0):

Emily,

Instead of `VLOOKUP`, have you tried a nested `IF`?  If not, try

```
=IF(B4>=A18,C18,IF(B4>=A17,C17,IF(B4>=A16,C16,IF(B4>=A15,C15,IF(B4>=A14,C14,IF(B4>=A13,C13,IF(B4>=A12,C12,IF(B4>=A11,C11,IF(B4>=A10,C10,IF(B4>=A9,C9,IF(B4>=A8,C8,IF(B4>=A7,C7,ERROR))))))))))))
```

in cell `B5` under "NI Contracts TVC Range".

Let me know whether that does what you need.  If it does, we can work on the next step.